# Map standard blue marker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I have implemented the user location application for iphone using xcode but for some reason the standard blue marker is not appearing on the map. So plz if anyone has an idea why is this happening let me know. Thanks

Comment: im not exactly sure what do you mean but i was just following and already written code using mapkit and corelocation .

Comment: He means "post your code" and "describe what you've done to accomplish your goal." If you're "just following" code, then post a link to it (and try to take the time to understand it instead of just using copy/paste).

Comment: im not just copying and pasting i was just reading from a book !! but they never mentioned the part about the blue dot or which part in the code is responsible for it !! besides i have tried another code from a different source and it worked except that this time im getting the wrong location even though im showing the user location i.e something.userlocation = YES !!  I cant actually post it unless he needs to see a specific portion of it coz its long but i will post the part where im showing the user location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is an issue with the **simulator**:

- **CoreLocation** will properly return your current location based on your IP address.
- Regardless of what CoreLocation thinks, **MapKit** always thinks you're in Cupertino, California, at Apple's headquarters.

Combining these two together, when you draw your map and center it on the location provided by CoreLocation, you don't see the blue dot despite the fact that you have ShowsUserLocation turned on -- that's because **it's over in Cupertino**.

If you run the app on an actual device, CoreLocation and MapKit will be in sync and the blue dot will appropriately appear where you expect it to.

Comment: thank you this is ture, you have just proofed my friends theory behind it!

Answer (score 0):

The Sample Project [CurrentAddress](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CurrentAddress/) demonstrates the usage of MapKit to show the current location in the map.